# Why does my JQuery .Ajax load data into a new page instead of replacing the specified element?

Tags: jquery

When using JQuery .ajax my content is put into a new page instead of replacing the specified element.  I use something very similar in the same site with no problems, but this one section does not like something and throws this error:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

After selecting Continue it loads the data into a new page instead of the specified selector.

I have the following included in the _Layout page:

- < script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"/>
- < script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"/>
- < script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"/>

The page code is as follows:

```
<link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/Tasks.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSaveNewTicket').hide();
    $('#frmTaskDetail').one('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('tru dat');
        $.ajax(
        {
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#divTaskDetail').empty();                
                $('#divTaskDetail').html(data);
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('#hidTdAccId').val('');
                $('#hidTdUserId').val('');
                $('#hidTdTicketId').val('');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
</script>

<div id="divTaskDetail">
@using (Html.BeginForm("DetermineTicketAction", "Dispatch", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmTaskDetail" }))
{
<div style="background-color: #2C6B87; width: 99%; border: 1px black solid; text-align: left; text-indent: 5px; margin: 1% 0 0 0; padding: 5px 0 5px 0; font-size: 12px; color: white; font-weight: bold">
    Task Details
</div>
<div style="width: 99%; border: 1px black solid;">

    @Html.Hidden("AccountId")       
    @Html.Hidden("ContactId")
    @Html.Hidden("CompanyId")
    @Html.Hidden("TicketId")
    @Html.Hidden("TicketCreated")
    @Html.Hidden("Created")
    @Html.Hidden("TicketClosed")
    @Html.Hidden("isActive")

    <table id="tblTaskDetail" style="width: 100%; text-indent: 5px; color: White; margin: 0 auto; font-size: 12px; top: 0; left: 0;">                    
                <tr>
                    <td>Ticket ID</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("TicketId" ,null, new { @disabled = true })</td>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("Address", null, new {@disabled = true })</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date Created</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("Created",null, new { disabled = true })</td>
                    <td>City</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("City",null, new { disabled = true })</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Company Name</td>
                     <td>@Html.TextBox("CompanyName")<input type="button" id="addCompany" value="+" /></td>
                    <td>State</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("State",null, new { disabled = true })</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Customer Name</td>                    
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("ContactName")<input type="button" id="addContact" value="+" /></td>
                    <td>Zip Code</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("ZipCode", null, new { disabled = true })</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Category</td>
                    <td>@Html.DropDownList("CategoryId")</td>
                    <td>Phone Number</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("Phone", null, new { disabled = true })</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Status</td>
                    <td>@Html.DropDownList("StatusId")</td>
                    <td>E-mail</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("Email", null, new { disabled = true })</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Priority</td>
                    <td>@Html.DropDownList("PriorityId")</td>
                    <td>Paid</td>
                    <td>@Html.DropDownList("Paid")</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Task Description</td>
                    <td>@Html.Editor("Description")</td>
                    <td>Assign To</td>
                    <td>@Html.DropDownList("UserId")</td>
                </tr>       
    </table>
    <table style="width: 100%; text-indent: 5px; color: White; margin: 0 auto; font-size: 12px; top: 0; left: 0;">
        <tr>
            <td>Comments @Html.TextBox("Comments", "", new { style = "width: 15%" })</td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> 
                @Html.ListBox("CommentList", @ViewBag.CommentList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { id="CommentList", style = "font-size: 10px" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="hidden" id="hidTdAccId" name="hidTdAccId" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hidTdUserId" name="hidTdUserId" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hidTdTicketId" name="hidTdTicketId" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hidSubType" name="hidSubType" value="" />
</div>

<input type="submit" id="btnSave" name="btnSave" value="Save" />
<input type="button" id="btnClearTicket" name="btnClearTicket" value="New Ticket"/>
<input type="submit" id="btnSaveNewTicket" name="btnNewTicket" value="Save New Ticket" />
<input type="submit" id="btnGetDetail" name="btnGetDetail"  style="visibility: hidden"  />
}
</div>
```

Any help/thoughts are appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: right at $(document).ready(function () {  and the entire block gets highlighted.  using a the IE developer tool, i can't even step into it.  When I try it just throws back the new page.

Comment: It looks like jQuery isn't loaded before you call $(document).ready

Comment: wouldn't it load the jquery first, as i put the call in on the _Layout page?

Comment: I'm not sure but if you can post the generated HTML we can see.

Comment: have you tried other web development tools like Firefox's Firebug or Chrome's Web Developer? this two usually provide more detailed information than IE's Developer tool.

Comment: I tried and get the same result, same info.  Just fyi, though, i am tasked with getting this to work specifically for IE.

Comment: Musa, I tried to add the generated code in an edit but it won't take.  I did take a look at it, though.  The includes appear at the top of the generated page code.  Does that mean it is loaded though?  Also, the other ajax methods i am using work fine and use those same includes so i imagine that it is loaded.

Comment: Ok apologies, I gave out some wrong info... it works on Chrome, but IE still has the exact same problem

Comment: I used the error console on firefox.  It shows "ReferenceError: $ is not defined".  That goes along with the jquery scripts not working theory but still don't know how to fix it.  Adding the reference directly to that page doesn't work.  Thoughts?

Comment: still having difficulties.  I've determined that if i comment out the first and third jquery tabs, everything works fine.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the Jquery ajax works fine in chrome/safari, but it would not work for IE.  Replacing JQuery Ajax with the Ajax helper did the trick for me.

Thanks for the help and suggestions.  +1 for your time and intelligent approach.